# How to avoid garbage collection Stop the World Events in IBM Java/JVM

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, aix

working on a in-memory application based on wildfly with infinispan, we are facing problems with IBM Java implementation (on AIX).

In Oracle the new strategy G1 Garbage Collection was introduced to avoid long garbage collection stopping the JVM during full-GC's. As far as I know, IBM doesn't implement this strategy in their Java Implementation. So how to deal with large heap online applications on IBM Java, especially how to avoid or at least minimize stop-the-world garbage collections.

Thank, BR Klaus

Comment: Afaik IBM Jvms offer multiple different GCs, just like OpenJDK. Have you checked their documentation?

Comment: yes i have. but even with -Xgcpolicy:optavgpause the JVM is running in stop-the-world events

Comment: in oracle jvm it's possible to minimize the pause times by use of parameters like -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200. I could not find that IBM is offering anything like this...

Comment: worth looking at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_8.0.0/com.ibm.java.aix.80.doc/diag/tools/metro_trouble_verbose.html  a couple of links off of it, let's you specify metronome behavior

Comment: `bash-4.3$ java -Xgcpolicy=metronome                           
JVMJ9VM007E Nicht erkannte Befehlszeilenoption: -Xgcpolicy=metronome
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.`

Comment: `java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pap6480sr3fp22-20161213_02(SR3 FP22))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.8, JRE 1.8.0 AIX ppc64-64 Compressed References 20161209_329148 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - R28_20161209_1345_B329148
JIT  - tr.r14.java.green_20161207_128946
GC   - R28_20161209_1345_B329148_CMPRSS
J9CL - 20161209_329148)
JCL - 20161213_01 based on Oracle jdk8u111-b14`

Comment: Metronome seems a concept fitting to my needs, but Metronome is not available for AIX, only Intel/AMD64. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_7.1.0/com.ibm.java.lnx.71.doc/user/mgc/metronome.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The G1 collector performs incremental collection (and compaction) of the old gen. heap space.  However, if it is unable to keep up with the rate of promotion from the young gen. it will resort to a full stop-the-world compacting collection, so you can still see significant spikes in latency (pauses) with G1.  G1 divides the heap space into regions so the young and old generations become logical areas of memory (each is a group of regions) rather than contiguous areas of virtual memory.  By doing this, regions can be processed independently of each other and those with fewer live objects prioritised over those with more to improve collection efficiency.

IBM have different policies to those provided in OpenJDK (and thus Hotspot from Oracle).  There are two that you should look at: gencon, which is a concurrent mark sweep algorithm, and metronome, which is designed to be a much more realtime collector.  Metronome is only supported on Linux, however.  Even this will fall back to a full STW collection so may have significant pauses in extreme situations.

Unfortunately, on AIX, gencon is the best option for minimising pause times.  Since this is a generational collector you can reduce pause times by minimising the number of long-lived objects generated by your code.  That way the objects are collected during a minor collection and do not get promoted to the old gen.  It is the major collections (of the old gen.) that will cause the longer pauses.